# How to print the key while value search is true in multi-values hashmap?

Tags: java, data-structures

So the program that I've created recently, there are multi-values in the hashmap, here is the program:

```
    studentID.put("P2530001", "P2530230" + "P2534141");
    studentID.put("P2531120", "P2530201");
    String SearchValue = sc.nextLine();
    boolean found = studentID.values().stream().anyMatch(value -> value.contains(SearchValue));

    if (found == true) {
        System.out.println("The P number that you entered is: " + SearchValue);
        System.out.println("P number exist, here is the assigned mentor:");
        System.out.println();// print the key when passed value search
    } else {
        System.out.println("The P number that you entered is: " + SearchValue);
        System.out.println("P number does not exist!");
    }
```

I've try using studentID.contains.Values(SearchValue);, but it's not working, can anyone helps and tells me what should I put in the program please, thank you.

Comment: Question: The P numbers appear to be both keys and values in your hashmap.  Was this the intention?  What is your hashmap supposed to be representing here?

Comment: So key representing mentor, values are mentees, when mentees value is searched, mentor (key) should display on screen to user

Answer (score 1):

You could use below code:

```
        Optional<Map.Entry<String, String>>
        result = studentID.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().contains(SearchValue)).findFirst();

    if (result.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println("The P number that you entered is: " + SearchValue);
        System.out.println("P number exist, here is the assigned mentor:");
        System.out.println(result.get().getKey());// print the key when passed value search
    } else {
        System.out.println("The P number that you entered is: " + SearchValue);
        System.out.println("P number does not exist!");
    }
```